# Deploy Nuxt PWA to s3

Tags: amazon-s3, vuejs2, nuxt.js

I'd like to deploy my PWA as a static site so that I can host it on S3. When I run Nuxt Build using SPA mode in the config; I get a "public" folder instead of a "dist" folder. The public folder contains a _nuxt folder with the index.html. If I just open the index.html, I get a 404 error on all other files as they are trying to be fetched from the _nuxt directory while actually being in root, [as seen here](https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/issues/1474).

If I deploy the entire _nuxt folder to S3, then I can't sent index.html as the homepage as its not in root.

Accessing website.s3.com/_nuxt shows the loader but shows an error in the console: Loading chunk {n} failed.

How do I deploy a Nuxt SPA PWA to s3?

Comment: there should be index.html in same level as _nuxt folder.

Answer (score 2):

TLDR; use `nuxt generate` to make a `dist` directory and upload that.  Only works on Universal apps.

From [here](https://nuxtjs.org/guide/commands),

- `nuxt build`

  - build nuxt app as a Node.js server
  - `nuxt start` runs the code in `.nuxt/index.js`.
  - for this, you'll need a server process (Heroku, Docker, etc)
- `nuxt generate`

  - build your nuxt app as static site
  - [options for deployment here](https://nuxtjs.org/faq/github-pages)